# Tablet won't boot Windows 10 installation flash drive - BIOS ignores boot priority setting

Tags: windows-10, boot, installation, usb-flash-drive

I installed Win 10 on my ASUS T200TA-CP003H. By mistake I chose 32 bit which caused a number of problems, especially with the sound card.

So I decided to install Win 10 64 bit. I prepared a usb-flash drive with Windows' Media Creation Tool,
BUT
every time I set the tablet to boot from the flash drive, the drive will be shortly contacted, but the system then goes on booting from c:

And, YES, I have set the Bios' boot priority correctly.

I'd be very grateful for some good ideas.

Answer (score 0):

On powering on your machine can select the boot device by pressing either F12 or Del on the BIOS screen and selecting your flash drive.

Alternatively you can access BIOS by holding down shift while choosing restart.

After that, the blue boot options menu displays from there hit Troubleshoot>Advanced options>UEFI Firmware Settings and click restart

Your system will restart and take you to the BIOS.

You can then reorder boot options from the Boot tab. Select your flash drive make sure it is top priority or Boot Option #1.

Comment: I have already done that. The effect is as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to run the Media Creation Tool another time or using a different flash drive?
Possibly the system correctly tries to boot the flash drive but fails, because the Windows PE on it is damaged for whatever reason, and then switches to the next valid device in the boot order, which is C:.

Redoing the drive could perhaps clear out that error and the next boot could work.

Comment: Nope, sorry. That's not it.

After some research, I think there's a kind of boot override which is switched to fastest. However, I cannot change the override.